# state.map is not a function React-Native

Tags: react-native

I am facing a problem in a project, the following error occurs when I run the apk:

> state.map is not a function React-Native
>    who doesn't take .map.

The code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Picker } from '@react-native-community/picker';
import axios from 'axios';

const Formulario = () => {
    const [moneda, guardarMoneda] = useState('');
    // este primer state de criptomoneda sirve para saber la seleccion del usuario
    const [criptomoneda, guardarCriptomoneda] = useState('');
    // este segundo muestra el estado de las 10 criptomonedas mas importantes
    const [criptomonedas, guardarCriptomonedas] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        const consultarApi = async () => {
            const url = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/top/totaltoptiervolfull?limit=10&tsym=USD';
            const resultado = await axios.get(url);
            guardarCriptomonedas(resultado.data.Data);
            console.log(resultado.data.Data);
        };
        consultarApi();

    }, []);
    console.log(criptomonedas);

    const obtenerMoneda = moneda => {
        guardarMoneda(moneda);
    };

    const obtenerCriptoMoneda = cripto => {
        guardarCriptomoneda(cripto);
    };
});
```

Inside the "return()" the problem appears in "criptomonedas.map":

```js
<Picker
    selectedValue={criptomoneda}
    onValueChange={cripto => obtenerCriptoMoneda(cripto)}>
    <Picker.Item label="- Seleccione -" value=""/>

    {criptomonedas.map(cripto => (
        <Picker key={cripto.CoinInfo.Id} label={cripto.CoinInfo.FullName} value={cripto.CoinInfo.Name}/>
    ))};
</Picker>
```

[Error on device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuGji.png)

Comment: Please translate your question into English. This will enable developers over the work to help you answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

change to this:

```js
//...
        {criptomonedas && Array.isArray(criptomonedas) && criptomonedas.map(cripto => (
        <Picker key={cripto.CoinInfo.Id} label={cripto.CoinInfo.FullName} value={cripto.CoinInfo.Name}/>
         ))};
// ...
```

Looks like your `criptomonedas` is not an array in first render.

Also you can check it before render picker:

```
if (!criptomonedas || !Array.isArray(criptomonedas))
   return <ActivityIndicator>
return <Picker/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Picker
                selectedValue = {moneda}
                onValueChange={  moneda => obtenerMoneda(moneda)  }
                itemStyle={{  height:120 }}
                >
               <Picker.Item label="- Seleccione -" value=''/>
                { ( criptomonedas || [] ).map( cripto=> ( <Picker.Item  key={ cripto.CoinInfo.Id } label={ cripto.CoinInfo.FullName } value={ cripto.CoinInfo.Name }/>) ) }
            </Picker>
```

Comment: Don't just post the code, also add a few words explaining why this code should work and what was wrong in the code posted in the question.